# Rock, Paper, Scissors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm on a codecademy lesson (found [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/1/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)) but keeps telling me "Your code returned 'rock wins' instead of 'paper wins' when the inputs are paper and rock", why? It should be correct. Since it's talking about 'rock wins' then it's talking about rock vs scissors. So why is it saying that "instead of paper wins" when there isn't even paper involved in the only outcome of 'rock wins'?

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {  

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors");
    } else {
        return ("rock wins");
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock");
    } else {
        return ("paper wins");
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors");
    } else {
        return ("scissors wins");
    }

};
```

Comment: `if (choice1 === "paper") { if (choice2 === "rock"); }` is not how you  test if both conditions are true or whatever you are trying to do with that. Read up on logical operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://bit.ly/19NPQLh

Comment: Problem semicolons after `if` statements.

Comment: That tutorial must be awful. Awful.

Comment: A simple algorithm is to take all the possible choices and put them in array in order, then compare by index; if it's higher, then it wins.

Comment: @elclanrs He may be not free to choose how he's going to code it: he's  following an interactive tutorial.

Comment: what's the point of following a tutorial and then ask the solution in here? There's even a "Hint" section with 99% of the solution code on that site.

Comment: `key = [choice1, choice2].sort().join(""); winners = { rockscissors: "rock", paperrock: "paper", paperscissors: "scissors" }; winners[key] + " wins"
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your first condition:

```
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors");
} else {
    return ("rock wins");
}
```

So if `choice1` is rock, you enter the `if`-block (which doesn't actually return anything, but since in this case `choice1` is actually `"paper"` it goes into the `else`-block, which unconditionally returns `"rock wins"`. Try refactoring it to be something like this:

```
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
}

if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return ("rock wins");
    } else {
        return ("paper wins");
    }
}

if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return ("paper wins");
    } else {
        return ("scissors wins");
    }
}

if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return ("scissors wins");
    } else {
        return ("rock wins");
    }
}
```

But hey, let's get fancy. Try putting your choices into an array:

```
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
```

Now, notice that the item to the right always beats the item to the left (if we consider that the array wraps around). How can we use this to simplify the code? Well we can just compare the indexes of each choice, taking care to handle the edge case of scissors vs. rock:

```
var x = choices.indexOf(choice1),
    y = choices.indexOf(choice2);
if (x === y) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
} else if (x > y) {
    if (x == 3 && y == 0) {
        return choice2 + " wins";
    } else {
        return choice1 + " wins";
    }
} else {
    return choice2 + " wins";
}
```

But we can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) (`%`) here to handle the edge case more easily:

```
var choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    var x = choices.indexOf(choice1),
        y = choices.indexOf(choice2);
    if (x === y) {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }

    return (((x - y) % 3) > 0 ? choice1 : choice2) + " wins";
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You could consider to use else-if on primary conditions

Answer (score 1):

Your function will always return "rock wins" when choice1 is not "rock". This is because you have used the if - else statement.

What you are doing is:
if choice1 is rock do something
else return "rock wins"

I will give you the first statement:

```
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") return ("rock wins");
        if (choice2 === "paper") return ("Paper wins");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/e68eN/)***

There are interesting choices you made when using the if statements. There shouldn't be semi colons after them. Also, the logic composition can struggle when using many if then else statements. Often, it is best to use a [switch case statement<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in these situations.

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
 if(choice1==choice2)return "The result is a tie!";
 switch(choice1+choice2){
    case "rockscissors": case "scissorsrock":
        return "rock wins";
    case "rockpaper": case "paperrock":
        return "paper wins";
    default: return "scissors wins";
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors");
} else {
    return ("rock wins");
}
```

Look at this again.  You say:

IF choice1 === rock, THEN
    IF choice2 === scissors THEN DO NOTHING
ELSE (choice1 is not rock)
    return 'rock wins'

This is a case where explicit braces would help.  I'm guessing you meant to do this:

```
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
    }
} else {
    return ("rock wins");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the data is very controlled, you can just do:

> if in (*choice1*+""+*choice2*) you find "**ks**", "**rr**" or "**sp**", you *choice1*
>   won, else lost <sub>(example below)</sub>

```
function getWinner(choice1, choice2){
    var both_str, after_removing;

    if(choice1 == choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    both_str = (choice1 + "" + choice2);
    after_removing = both_str.replace(RegExp("ks|rr|sp", "g"), "");

    return (choice1 + ((both_str.length - after_removing.length) ? " won" : " lost"));
}
```

And you get the following results:

```
console.log(getWinner("scissors", "paper")); //scissors won
console.log(getWinner("rock", "scissors")); //rock won
console.log(getWinner("paper", "rock")); //paper won

console.log(getWinner("scissors", "rock")); //scissors lost
console.log(getWinner("rock", "paper")); //rock lost
console.log(getWinner("paper", "scissors")); //paper lost

console.log(getWinner("scissors", "scissors")); //The result is a tie!
console.log(getWinner("rock", "rock")); //The result is a tie!
console.log(getWinner("paper", "paper")); //The result is a tie!
```